# Constructor not defined for constructor that's defined

Tags: apex

Pretty new to development, so I'm probably missing something easy.  From advice on this site, I'm trying to move my org's triggers into a trigger handler to be more manageable.  I've started converting my triggers into classes, however when I try to call a method of one of these classes, I'm getting a Constructor not defined error.

Here is my constructor:

```
public class AddProductFromOfferingId { 

    Map<Id, Lead> newLeads;

    public AddProductFromOfferingId(Map<Id, Lead> newTriggerLeads)
    {
        newLeads = newTriggerLeads;
    }
}
```

And here's where I try to call the constructor:

```
public void beforeInsert(SObject so)
    {
        // Cast the SObject to an Lead
        Lead theLead = (Lead)so;

        if(theLead.Offering_ID__c != null)
        {
            AddProductFromOfferingId addProd = new AddProductFromOfferingId(Trigger.newMap);
        }
```

The full error is: Constructor not defined: `[AddProductFromOfferingId].<Constructor>(Map<Id, SOBject>)`.

In the constructor, I've named it `AddProductFromOfferingId`, requiring one `Id, Lead` map to be passed in.  In my TriggerHandler class (second code snippet), I'm passing in a map.  Can I not use Trigger.newMap in this way?

Update:

Thanks @BrianMansfield, your comment gave me what I needed.  Adding the following to the handler class fixed my issue:

```
Map<Id, Lead> newMapFromTrigger = (Map<Id, Lead>) Trigger.newMap;
```

Comment: Where is beforeInsert being called from? It's probably because you've defined the constructor to take in a Map<Id, Lead> and you're passing it a Map<Id, *base* sObject>...try explicitly casting Trigger.newMap to a Map<Id, Lead>

Comment: beforeInsert is being called in my LeadHandler class, which is where I plan to call all triggers-turned-classes.  When I try to set Trigger.newMap to an <Id, Lead> map, I get an error saying the types don't match, so I believe you're right!  Just need to figure out how to get Trigger.newMap to change into an <Id, Lead> map instead of an <Id, SObject> map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of a way around it but you can cast the `Map<ID,sObject>` to the `Map<ID,Lead>` as follows:

```
//This lines could simply be your trigger.newMap records, query is just an example
Map<ID,sObject> l = New Map<ID,sObject>([Select ID From Lead limit 1]);

//Actual conversion here
Map<ID,Lead> a = New Map<ID,Lead>((Lead[])l.values());
```

BUT, I would change (if it makes sense) the constructor to:

```
AddProductFromOfferingId(Map<ID,sObject> newTriggerLeads){
     //If null or no records, nothing to do
     if(newTriggerLeads == null || newTriggerLeads.isEmpty()) return;

     //If we have lead records cast to a list of leads and do what we need to
     if(newTriggerLeads[0].getsObjectType() == Lead.sObjectType()){
          Lead[] theLeads = (List<Leads>)newTriggerLeads.values();
     }else{ //Not leads, do nothing
        return;
     }

}
```

Or something like that

Comment: ??  why is `Account` showing up in your first code sample?  typo?

Comment: @cropredy - oops. I had sample as Account and was trying to change it to lead when posting. Did not get them all. Should be good now, thanks

Comment: Thanks @Eric!  Would you still need to include the line `if(newTriggerLeads[0].getObjectType() == Lead.sObjectType())` if this is only called on a Lead Handler class?  For example, if I have a handler class for each SObject, and this method is only called for leads, that shouldn't be necessary right?  Just trying to make sure I understand!

Comment: @krisuvik - correct